# Navit and Debug it

Tags: debugging, routes, navit

Does anybody know how i can debug [Navit](http://www.navit-project.org/). It doesn't matter if i can do it in MS Visual Studio or Eclipse. It doesn't matter if I have to do that under Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Navit is a C application, and can be debugged using any debugger that can debug C programs.

The details depend on your development environment (IDE/editor, compiler, operating system).

For development on Linux, popular debugger options include:

- `gdb` (text-based)
- [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (graphical)
- [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) (graphical)
- [Pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) (vim plugin)

Some notes:

- Usually you want to build in debug mode (cmake option `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`). This will build with symbols and disable optimizations, which makes debugging easier.
- When running the `navit` binary without installing it, you must run it from the directory it is created in - otherwise it will not find the plugins (which are compiled to separate libraries). Take care to configure the current directory correctly in the debugger.